# Output of a script to a new unsaved text file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, notepad

I execute a few commands in remote server and save the output to a new text file. The twist here is that I  want to leave the option to save or scrape the text file to user itself. I'm stuck at how to write all the output to a new notepad file. I'm also not sure if I can write the output in the same unsaved notepad file.

currently `$item` has the output

```
$item >> C:\Users\Documents\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt
```

required:

```
$x = Start-Process 'C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe'
```

I can invoke it, but don't know how to write the output from the foreach loop to this notepad instance.

Comment: How do you mean "write to an unsaved file"?  If you don't save the file, how will you see what's in it?  Do you mean you want to open the notepad program and write content to the editor's window without saving?  A better option may be to write to a temp file, then have the user decide whether to save that file somewhere permanent.  However, this feels like an XYProblem (http://xyproblem.info/)... what's the root issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: If you are looking to push content to an open notepad window, take a look at this `sendkeys` solution: https://superuser.com/a/1250038/156700.  However, such solutions are not nice (e.g. if someone closes notepad, or changes the app focus, in parallel to the program running those key sends could go anywhere, having unforeseen consequences).

Comment: ps. Also found this method, which may be of interest: http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/send-text-to-notepad

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script based on the one [here](http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/send-text-to-notepad).
I've amended it to allow you to re-use the reference to the application, so that you can make subsequent calls to the same method, and access the same instance of notepad.  This version also allows you to append to the notepad instance; so that the content isn't overwritten on each call (though you can include the `Flush` parameter should you wish your new text to replace the existing content; as if you'd run a `Clear-Notepad` command first.

Since this version allows you to pass in a `Process` to allow re-use of the existing notepad instance (without the risk of capturing any arbitrary running instance of notepad by fetching any notepad instance from the running processes), I've also left the option to use any process; so you could use a different program should you wish... However, this script isn't tested for other programs / doesn't have any special logic to cater for them; so should be tested for applications before being used with them.

```
#requires -Version 2

#based on Out-Notepad script from http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/send-text-to-notepad; only amended to allow appending.
function Out-Application {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByString')]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ParameterSetName = 'ByString')]
        [AllowEmptyString()] 
        [String]$InputString
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ParameterSetName = 'ByObject')]
        [AllowEmptyString()] 
        [PSObject]$InputObject
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
        [System.Diagnostics.Process]$TargetApplication = (Start-Process 'notepad' -PassThru) #default the target application to a new instance of notepad
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
        [String]$SubWindowName = "Edit" #this is the notepad edit box; for other apps we may want a different class/window name (or this may be completely innappropriate; only really designed for notepad, but with some pieces left flexible in case we can re-use elsewhere)
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
        [Switch]$ReturnProcess
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
        [Switch]$Flush
    )
    begin {
        [int]$WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C
        [int]$WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E
        [int]$EM_SETSEL = 0x00B1
        [int]$EM_REPLACESEL = 0x00C2
        [Type]$winApi = 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType.AutoGeneratedTypes.APISendMessage' -as [Type]
        if ($winApi -eq $null) {
            $winApiImports = '
                [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
                [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]public static extern int SendMessageGetTextLength(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
                [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
            '
            $winApi = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $winApiImports -Name APISendMessage -PassThru
        }
    }
    process {
        [pscustomobject]$pipelineOutput = [pscustomobject]@{}
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByObject') {
            $pipelineOutput | Add-Member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' -Name 'InputObject' -Value $InputObject
            $InputString = $InputObject | Format-List | Out-String
        } else {
            $pipelineOutput | Add-Member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' -Name 'InputString' -Value $InputString
        }
        if ($ReturnProcess) {
            $pipelineOutput | Add-Member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' -Name 'TargetApplication' -Value $TargetApplication        
        }
        $TargetApplication.WaitForInputIdle() | Out-Null
        $hwnd = $TargetApplication.MainWindowHandle
        [IntPtr]$childWindow = $winApi::FindWindowEx($hwnd, [IntPtr]::Zero, $SubWindowName, $null) 
        if ($Flush) {
            #specifying flush removes all content and pastes the new data in its place; useful if you wanted to watch the latest value in notepad without having a historic feed
            $winApi::SendMessage($childWindow, $formFeed, [IntPtr]::Zero, $InputString) | Out-Null
        } else {
            #if not flushing then we append content after existing content
            [int]$length = $winApi::SendMessageGetTextLength($childWindow, $WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, [IntPtr]::Zero, [IntPtr]::Zero)
            $winApi::SendMessage($childWindow, $EM_SETSEL, $length, $length) | Out-Null
            $winApi::SendMessage($childWindow, $EM_REPLACESEL, 1, $InputString) | Out-Null
        }
        $pipelineOutput
    }
}
Clear-Host
$notepad = Get-Process | Out-String | Out-Application -ReturnProcess | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'TargetApplication' -First 1
Get-Service | Out-Application -TargetApplication $notepad | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1):

as ref http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/out-notepad-send-information-to-notepad

```
  requires -Version 2
    function Out-Notepad
{
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [String]
    [AllowEmptyString()] 
    $Text
  )

  begin
  {
    $sb = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
  }

  process
  {
    $null = $sb.AppendLine($Text)
  }
  end
  {
    $text = $sb.ToString()

    $process = Start-Process notepad -PassThru
    $null = $process.WaitForInputIdle()


    $sig = '
      [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
      [DllImport("User32.dll")]public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
    '

    $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name APISendMessage -PassThru
    $hwnd = $process.MainWindowHandle
    [IntPtr]$child = $type::FindWindowEx($hwnd, [IntPtr]::Zero, "Edit", $null)
    $null = $type::SendMessage($child, 0x000C, 0, $text)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do somethinge like that:

```
$Trace = "Start log`r`n"

#Do stuff

$Trace += "Log output`r`n"

if ($UserInput -eq $true) {
    $Trace | Out-File -FilePath "YourFile"
}
```

**EDIT**

That is a quick solution how you cloud display the text without writing it to a file and ask the user afterwards.

```
$Trace | Out-GridView -Wait

$Result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Do you want to save the file","Save",1)

If ($Result -eq "Yes")
{
    $Trace | Out-File -FilePath "YourPath"
}
```

Comment: Check out my answer agian. I added a quick solution